# Error while packaging Python program with py2ap

Tags: python, py2app

Development environment:
1.MAC 10.12.4
2.python 2.7
**Error info:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 19, in <module>
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/py2app-0.14-py2.7.egg/py2app/build_app.py", line 825, in run
    self._run()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/py2app-0.14-py2.7.egg/py2app/build_app.py", line 1040, in _run
    self.run_normal()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/py2app-0.14-py2.7.egg/py2app/build_app.py", line 1253, in run_normal
    o = __import__(m1, fromlist=[m2])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyQt5/uic/port_v3/ascii_upper.py", line 24, in <module>
    _ascii_trans_table = bytes.maketrans(b'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
AttributeError: type object 'str' has no attribute 'maketrans'
holysordeiMac:Spider_reddit holysor$
```

[Image of the traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o98oX.png)

Comment: Thank you for correcting my problem

Comment: This problem has been plagued me, tried a lot of ways, do not know how to solve